# Can not see push statuses in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-docs

As in the console google play view the status for each sent message?(Need to view the statuses without specifying a specific device_id. View all statuses at once.)
Is this possible?

Here is the help from google.

```
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268
```

Once your app is published, you can view FCM statistics on your app's Statistics page.

```
Sign in to your Play Console.
Select an app.
On the left menu, click Statistics.
Next to "Statistics," click the drop-down and select FCM statistics.
```

I have a drop-down list(probably this is a bug of documentation):

```
Firebase Cloud Messaging
Сообщения FCM
Регистрации в FCM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Need to view the statuses without specifying a specific device_id. View all statuses at once. Is this possible?*

This is currently not possible. As stated in the 
[help doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268) you linked (emphasis mine):

> You can look up messages sent through Firebase Cloud Messaging with a **registration token** or **message ID**.